# ActiveRecord::Relation getting methods added to it - Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm seeing very strange behavior in Rails 3.2.20.

I created an example app with 2 simple models.

```
class Bro < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cool_story

  scope :hey_bro, -> do
    where(nil)
  end
end

class Dawg < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :where_you_at
end
```

From irb:

```
 jonesdeini@scooty_puff_jr ~/example$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.20)
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Dawg.where(nil).respond_to? :hey_bro
 => false 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > Bro.hey_bro
  Bro Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "bros".* FROM "bros" 
 => [] 
1.9.3-p125 :003 > Dawg.where(nil).respond_to? :hey_bro
 => false 
1.9.3-p125 :004 > Bro.where(nil).hey_bro
  Bro Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "bros".* FROM "bros" 
 => [] 
1.9.3-p125 :005 > Dawg.where(nil).respond_to? :hey_bro
 => true
```

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

The complete code is here: https://github.com/jonesdeini/rails3.2-weirdness

Update:
The strangeness can be traced to here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.20/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L26

super returns true after a scope has been added to a where. (probably better explained by the output in this gist https://gist.github.com/jonesdeini/dbe3124b2c31bd31ed31)

Comment: If I had time, I'd dig into this more. But if I were you, I'd start by looking at this: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.20/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb#L3-L11

Comment: ^ AR overrides the behavior of `#respond_to?`. I'd put a debugger in the method I linked to above and try to figure out what's going on.